# How access to relationship in accessors method in model | laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I have this `Course` model that related to an `academicPath`, Now I'm creating this accessor called `long_name` but cannot access the academic_path_name under the `academicPath`.

```
class Course extends Model
{
    /// ...

    protected $appends = [
        'long_name'
    ];

    public function academicPath()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(\App\Models\AcademicPath::class);
        // return $this->hasOne(\App\Models\AcademicPath::class);
    }


    public function getLongNameAttribute()
    {
        return $this->academic_path->academic_path_name . " [" . $this->course_year . "]" ;
    }
}
```

Error :

```
{message: "Attempt to read property "academic_path_name" on null", exception: "ErrorException",…}
exception: "ErrorException"
file: "/var/www/html/app/Models/Course.php"
line: 57
message: "Attempt to read property "academic_path_name" on null"
trace: [{file: "/var/www/html/app/Models/Course.php", line: 57, function: "handleError",…}, {,…}, {,…}, {,…},…]
```

Answer (score 0):

**Solved**, by replacing

`$this->academic_path`
with
`$this->academicPath`

and make sure that the value is not empty because it's not required.

```
public function getLongNameAttribute()
    {

        if (is_null($this->academicPath)) {
            return  "... [" . $this->course_year . "]";
        } else {
            return $this->academicPath->academic_path_name 
                        . " [" . $this->course_year . "]";
        }
    }
```